# After saving parent entity I am losing child entity data even I sent child data in payload

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mapping

The Main Entity Student_table and Associated entities are Address, Student_Examinations and Student_Course_table so on.....

In payload I sent Main entity along with Student_Examinations and Student_Course_table after hitting a send in Post man.
Main Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "student" })
@Where(clause = "del_flag='N'")
public class Student extends RecordTimeStamp {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_number")
    private String studentNumber;

    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private StudentAddress studentAddress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<StudentExaminations> studentExaminations;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<StudentCourses> studentCourses;
```

Student Examination associated entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Student_Examinations")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "student" })
public class StudentExaminations extends RecordTimeStamp {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_examination_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int studentExaminationId;

    @Column(name = "student_number", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String studentNumber;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_number", referencedColumnName = "student_number")
    private Student student;
}
```

Student courses associated entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Student_Courses")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "student" })
public class StudentCourses extends RecordTimeStamp {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_course_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int studentCourseId;

    @Column(name = "student_number", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String studentNumber;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_number", referencedColumnName = "student_number")
    private Student student;
```

Service for main enity

```
>! inside a service
>! I am calling save
 public Student addStudent(Student studentData) {

Student studentSaved = studentRepo.save(studentData);

}
```

JSON PAYLOAD

```
{
"rcreDate": 1687764060323,
"lchgDate": 1687764060323,
"rcreUserId": "admin",
"lchgUserId": "admin",
"lchgEvent": "STUDENT_REGISTRATION",
"studentNumber": "2020010",
"studentName": "TEST1",
"userName": "admin",
"studentExaminations": [
    {
        "rcreDate": 1687774980000,
        "lchgDate": 1687774980000,
        "rcreUserId": "admin",
        "lchgUserId": "admin",
        "lchgEvent": "STUDENT_REGISTRATION",
        "studentExaminationId": 0,
        "studentExamType":"Semester 1",
        "delFlag": "N"
    }
],
 "studentCourses": [
    {
        "rcreDate": 1687787400000,
        "lchgDate": 1687787400000,
        "rcreUserId": "admin",
        "lchgUserId": "admin",
        "lchgEvent": "STUDENT_REGISTRATION",
        "studentCourseId": 0,
        "courseName": "Maths",
        "delFlag": "N"
    }
 ],
 "studentStatus": "DRAFT",
"isRejectedBoolean": false,
"isApprovedBoolean": false,
"delFlag": "N"
```

}

After save I can not see course data in studentSaved but I can see studentExamination

the post request have data main_table, Student_Examinations, Student_Course_table data.
After Saving to main table I am not getting Student_Course_table data onto StudentSaved but Student_Examinations saving into main table.

I am expecting to save studentCourses also but I am not able to getting save into studentSaved after save. I am losing studentCourse data.

Comment: can you add  the json payload used

Comment: I am edited you can see now, one more entity has more columns but I did not sent in quetion